# How export grid to excel in vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I use vaadin in my project, and i cant understend how export grid to excel.

I have:

```
Grid<Vlr> gridVlr = new Grid<>("Vlrs"); 
gridBank.setItems(VlrList); // i used ArrayList
gridBank.addColumn(Vlr::getVlrId).setCaption("VlrId");

ExportExcelComponentConfiguration<Vlr> componentConfig1
    = new ExportExcelComponentConfigurationBuilder<Vlr>()
        .withGrid(gridVlr)
        .withVisibleProperties(new String[]{"Vlr ID"})
        .withHeaderConfigs(Arrays.asList(
            new ComponentHeaderConfigurationBuilder()
            .withAutoFilter(true)
            .withColumnKeys(new String[]{"Vlr Id"})
            .build()
        ))
        .withIntegerFormattingProperties(Arrays.asList("counter"))
        .withFloatFormattingProperties(Arrays.asList(
            "totalCosts",
            "differenceToMin"
        ))
        .withBooleanFormattingProperties(Arrays.asList("active"))
        //  .withColumnFormatters(columnFormatters)
        .build();

ExportExcelSheetConfiguration<Vlr> sheetConfig1
    = new ExportExcelSheetConfigurationBuilder<Vlr>()
        .withReportTitle("Grid (Default)")
        .withSheetName("Grid (default)")
        .withComponentConfigs(Arrays.asList(componentConfig1))
        .withIsHeaderSectionRequired(Boolean.TRUE)
        .withDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")
        .build();


ExportExcelConfiguration<Vlr> config
    = new ExportExcelConfigurationBuilder<Vlr>()
        .withGeneratedBy("Roman")
        .withSheetConfigs(Arrays.asList(sheetConfig1))
        .build();

ExportToExcel exportToExcel = new ExportToExcel(ExportType.XLSX, null);

Button buttonExport = new Button("Export to Excel", clickEvent -> {
    exportToExcel.export();
});

layout.addComponent(buttonExport);
```

What's my mistake?
 Maybe there is a simpler solution?

Comment: you forgot to say what problem you're having. That might make it easier for people to work out what the mistake could be.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation about file download in book of vaadin [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/LettingTheUserDownloadAFile.html). You are missing download "link" from your button.

Steps to download a file from button click are following

1. Create button with download resource
2. In `createResosurce` method write xlsx file on the server
3. Provide `StreamResource` to the file.